# Webpack change url in css files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have an issue in which I have to change all urls in css from '../images/' to '../../images' only in dev server. Because the structure of my dev version differs from the production.

I'm migrating now from gulp and cant resolve this problem.

This is my Webpack 3 dev config.

```js
const FilterWarningsPlugin = require('webpack-filter-warnings-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:5100', 'babel-polyfill', './src/index.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/public/js'),
        publicPath: '/barfe/ui/',
        filename: 'main.js'
    },
    context: path.resolve(__dirname),
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        hot: false,
        inline: false,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: '5100',
        index: 'index.html',
        historyApiFallback: true,
        headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
        setup(app) {
            app.get('/', (req, res) => {
                res.redirect(301, 'http://localhost:5100/barfe/ui/#/');
            });
        },
        proxy: {
            '/barfe/api': {
                target: 'https://555.555.55.555',
                secure: false
            }
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/i,
                use: ['resolve-url-loader', 'url-loader?limit=10000', 'img-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'resolve-url-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did it with using of

```js
 use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        'css-loader',
                        'resolve-url-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                })
```